# Property of an object, expected be a mailitem, generates '438' Run-time error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm trying to choose a folder then show a MsgBox with the number of emails sent during a set timeframe in that folder and all it's subfolders.

I can select a folder but I get

> '438' Run-time error: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

on the line after the "for" loop.

```
receive_datetime = objCurrentFolder.Items(i).SentOn
```

This is the whole macro:

```
Sub CountItems()
    Dim lItemsCount As Long
    
    StartDate = DateSerial(2018, 1, 1)
    EndDate = DateSerial(2020, 1, 1)
 
    'Select a folder
    Set objMainFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder
 
    If objMainFolder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "You choose select a valid folder!", _
          vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Warning for Pick Folder"
    Else
        'Initialize the total count
        lItemsCount = 0
        Call LoopFolders(objMainFolder, lItemsCount)
    End If
 
    'Display a message for the total count
    MsgBox "There are " & lItemsCount & " items in the " & _
      objMainFolder.Name & " folder Including its subfolders.", _
      vbInformation, "Count Items"
End Sub

Sub LoopFolders(ByVal objCurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder, lCurrentItemsCount As Long)
    Dim objSubfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Set receiveditems = objCurrentFolder.Items
    
    For i = receiveditems.Count To 1 Step -1
    ' the last item in the collection is your most recent email.
    ' This can be handy to know if your inbox is massive and 
    '  you want to include a Exit For at some point,
    '  e.g. when you run into a date < StartDate

        receive_datetime = objCurrentFolder.Items(i).SentOn
        If receive_datetime >= StartDate And receive_datetime <= EndDate Then
            lCurrentItemsCount = lCurrentItemsCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
 
    'Process all folders and subfolders recursively
    If objCurrentFolder.Folders.Count Then
        For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.Folders
            Call LoopFolders(objSubfolder, lCurrentItemsCount)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not all items are necessarily mailitems, and so might not have a SentOn property.  You first need to check if the item is a MailItem.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Tim Williams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/478884/tim-williams) helping me out. I think I got it to work by checking if it's a MailItem or not.

```
 Select Case True
        Case TypeOf objCurrentFolder.Items(i) Is Outlook.MailItem
            receive_datetime = objCurrentFolder.Items(i).SentOn
            If receive_datetime >= StartDate And receive_datetime <= EndDate Then
                lCurrentItemsCount = lCurrentItemsCount + 1
            End If
        Case Else
             lCurrentItemsCount = lCurrentItemsCount + 0
    End Select
```